# Modelling a Floating Gate Transistor

Tags: transistors, mosfet, ltspice, simulation, floating-gate

Does anyone know of a simple circuit diagram to implement in the likes of LTspice to show the operation of a floating gate transistor?

Would a capacitor on the gate of a standard transistor do the same job?

Comment: You mean a MOSFET?  Or IGBT?

Comment: MOSFET- to replicate the behaviour of an FGMOS

Comment: Oh, you mean a circuit where everything connected to the gate node is floating? Like in memory circuits?  I don't think you can truly float the gate node because SPICE needs to add a conductance on every node to solve the circuit matrix.  The wikipedia page on FGMOS references a textbook which supposedly has a method of doing an FGMOS simulation.

Answer (score 1):

> Would a capacitor on the gate of a standard transistor do the same job?

Not really, because the transistor depends on there being a DC electric field from the floating gate that acts on the "channel". A base of a regular BJT, when driven with DC through a capacitor, will not flow any current once that capacitor is charged, and thus won't make the transistor conduct, defeating the purpose of the whole exercise.

> Modelling a Floating Gate Transistor

Are you talking about an IGBT - insulated gate bipolar transistor? They have models available for most SPICE programs.

Comment: MOSFET - the likes of  FGMOS?

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know of a simple circuit diagram to implement in the likes
> of LTspice to show the operation of a floating gate transistor?

If you mean attached to air, then yes. You would put a very large resistor on the order of 10^9 to 10^12 Ohms and then attach that to a voltage source. You may also want to attach some capacitance, but that will depend on every bit of metal in the room or any conductive objects next to the gate. A few pF's would be a good start, but it will depend on what your voltage source is. If you are going to have someone touch this 'floating gate', it will looks something more like
[Human Body Model (HBM) ESD testing](http://www.aeroelectric.com/Reference_Docs/ESD/Human%20body%20model%20and%20ESD.pdf)

The problem is air is hard to characterize and changes based off of humidity air movement ect. If you want to take this circuit into the real world, it won't be that reliable, but it could tell you some things about how the circuit would behave.

> Would a capacitor on the gate of a standard transistor do the same
> job?

Not an ideal capacitor, you would also need parallel resistance.